# Start next text block below an image in a QTextDocument

Tags: qt, qt4

Currently I insert a block containing a newline character to do this:

```
  QTextDocument* myDocument = new QTextDocument(textEdit);
  textEdit->setDocument(myDocument);
  QTextCursor* myCursor = new QTextCursor(myDocument);

  // Insert an image
  QTextImageFormat imageFormat;
  imageFormat.setName("logo.jpg");
  myCursor->insertImage(imageFormat, QTextFrameFormat::InFlow);
  myCursor->insertText("\n");

  // Insert normal text
  myCursor->movePosition(QTextCursor::End);
  myCursor->insertText("test");
```

This seems pretty hacky. Is there a better way to make the next block of text start below the image, rather than to the right of it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is the best option You have..

Though, Your code always get a brand new QTextDocument.

Based on what Your ultimate goal is, maybe You would like to use

```
QTextDocument* myDocument = textEdit->document();
```

instead of

```
QTextDocument* myDocument = new QTextDocument(textEdit);
textEdit->setDocument(myDocument);
```

Comment: Ok, thanks. I was very new to QTextDocument so I guess since no one else had a better solution and you confirmed that mine is sane, I'll just go with that!